# How to start embedded development for developing a handheld game console?

Tags: embedded-systems, low-level

I work as a iPhone app developer now, so I know a bit of c, c++ and objective c. Also have fiddled with Java and many other. All of them have been just high level application/games development.

My final goal is to make a handheld game console. More like a home made NES/SNES handheld console or even an Atari. I have found out about RaspberryPI and Arduino. But I need more information about how to approach this.

1. How Do I learn to pick the best board/cpu/controller/GPU/LCD screen/LCD controller etc?
2. Will learning to make a NES emulator first help me understand this field? If so are there any tutorials?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My suggestion is buy one of the arduino kits related to this goal. A few examples:

[Fuzebox](http://www.ladyada.net/make/fuzebox/)

[image: Fuzebox]

[Hackvision](http://nootropicdesign.com/hackvision/index.html)

[image: Hackvision]

[Video Game Shield Kit](http://www.wayneandlayne.com/store/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=1&products_id=4)

[image: Video Game Shield Kit]

*How Do I learn to pick the best board/cpu/controller/GPU/LCD screen/LCD controller etc?*

Firstly you need know in depth a real machine. The arduinos are a very good option for this because are 100% open source and include documentation. Don't buy a RaspberryPI or others ARM boards because the most use closed drivers for the GPU and other pieces. If you finally decide buy a traditional ARM board (not a arduino with ARM processor), search a board with the GPU "mali".

*Will learning to make a NES emulator first help me understand this field? If so are there any tutorials?*

No. You will only learn a lot of assembler code :) . Probably, enhance your C skills are a better idea.

Don't be too ambitious at the beginning or your project will die. Step by step. My advice is:

- Buy a Kit.
- Read **all** the documentation.
- Program a simple game.
- Program a complex game.
- Enhance your game internally. Try different ideas for enhance the performance.
- Now you know well the platform.
- Read the code of your system. Kernel and low level libs.
- I'm sure that your system has bugs. Search and fix these.
- The code of your system is inefficient. Enhance the code.
- At this moment you know all your system with a very big depth.
- Now you can create anything. Congratulations :)